# Not able to get actions to fire USER_PRESENT or SCREEN_ON Android Emulator

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want to know when a user has turned their phone on eg. click the power button/possibly actually unlocked their phone. The ultimate goal is to update a widget's display after calling an API vs. using scheduled updates.

The issue is I've been scouring threads and I have not been able to get my logs to fire in Logcat. I have tried both `Receiver` and `Service` methods. Is what Is what I am attempting possible?

I have also tried setting the `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission in the manifest.

Some code context of what I have:

Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".CustomBroadcastRecveiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON">
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Optional service in manifest that I tried:

```
<service android:naem=".CustomService"/>
```

CustomBroadcastReceiver:

```
public class CustomBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i("MyTag", "broadcast receive"); // this does not run

    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT) {
      Log... // this doesn't run, same for ACTION_SCREEN_ON that would be in a new if block
    }
  }
}
```

I'm open to other alternatives. I can provide more context if necessary. I can expand more on my service implementation if that is the way to go assuming what I'm after is possible.

**Edit**
To add more context on how I used Elletlar's answer

In my MainActivity I added:

```
private static Context context;
```

Then inside onCreate:

```
context = getApplicationContext();
// instantiate my specific receiver
// set the code from answer below
```

Note: I am API 29 if it makes any difference.

Comment: Hi it_is_written. From the "android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" docs, "You cannot receive this through components declared in manifests, only by explicitly registering for it with Context#registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver, IntentFilter)." Regards.

Comment: That's interesting, thought you were going to point out service, I will look into that thanks. RTM. I also saw it mentioned about specific broadcasts enabled now, list of allowed global broadcasts I think, not sure if relevant.

Comment: I added a little sample below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the "android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" docs, "You cannot receive this through components declared in manifests, only by explicitly registering for it with

```
Context#registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver, IntentFilter).
```

Example of registering explicitly:

```
myReceiver = new MyReceiver();
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, I was hoping for some sample code as I am not an Android Developer was just trying to modify some tutorial code I found. I wanted to ask where does this go because I don't immediately see Context. From what I've seen you can infer Context as "this" in classes... would I do that in my main activity? That might be too much, anyway this is great as it is so thanks. I'm going to try it out.

Comment: I'll try in my widget provider as I have context there, not sure if that makes sense.

Comment: It is a little bit complex. Apps are not generally encouraged to listen for ACTION_SCREEN_ON because every app on the system would start running at once which is why we are made to register the filter in code rather than doing it implicitly in the manifest.

Comment: I would be a little bit hesitant to recommend an architecture without studying the full code and thinking about the Service limitations on current versions of Android, but it is technically possible to register for the receiver in a foreground service. But I would strongly recommend against it.

Comment: OMG I got it to work. Thank you! I put it in my MainActivity, used getApplicationContext(), will add more details to my question for other readers. You would not believe how many freaking SO posts I've been through, granted a lot of them are old eg. from 2013.

Comment: I literally just want a basic widget that gets updated when the user turns on their phone/logs in, this connects to an API to get data. This is for me, it's not a deployed app.

Comment: Registering in the Activity is safe. I was about to caution you about registering in the WidgetProvider because it is actually a BroadcastReceiver in diguise.  "A BroadcastReceiver object is only valid for the duration of the call to onReceive(Context, Intent). Once your code returns from this function, the system considers the object to be finished and no longer active."

Comment: Right, I also saw that you register the widget provider in the manifest, was thinking about what you originally said... but yeah I'm glad this will work.